# How to invoke " def imperativeBubbleSort[T <% Ordered[T]](source: Array[T]): Array[T] = { "

Tags: scala

The method imperativeBubbleSort has signature :

```
  def imperativeBubbleSort[T <% Ordered[T]](source: Array[T]): Array[T] = {
    for (i <- 0 until source.length - 1; j <- 0 until source.length - 1 - i) {
      if (source(j) > source(j + 1)) {
        val temp = source(j)
        source(j) = source(j + 1)
        source(j + 1) = temp
      }
    }
    source
  }
```

To call it I use :

```
 imperativeBubbleSort(3,2,1)
```

But receive error :

```
Multiple markers at this line - too many arguments for method imperativeBubbleSort: (source: Array[T])(implicit 
 evidence$1: T => Ordered[T])Array[T] - too many arguments for method imperativeBubbleSort: (source: 
 Array[T])(implicit evidence$1: T => Ordered[T])Array[T]
```

But does this function just takes one parameter ?

Does `[T <% Ordered[T]]` mean I need to add a type parameter which is subclass of Ordered ?

Comment: You need to pass an array - `imperativeBubbleSort(Array(3,2,1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you actually want a varargs method. Instead of `Array[T]`, use `T*` to specify a vararg type. Here's an updated version:

```
def imperativeBubbleSort[T <% Ordered[T] : ClassTag](inputs: T*): Array[T] = {
  val source = inputs.toArray
  for (i <- 0 until source.length - 1; j <- 0 until source.length - 1 - i) {
    if (source(j) > source(j + 1)) {
      val temp = source(j)
      source(j) = source(j + 1)
      source(j + 1) = temp
    }
  }
  source
}
```

Note that I had to add the `ClassTag` restriction on the `T` type. This is because the `toArray` method in `Seq` requires it in order to create a new array. This is because in Scala the varargs are passed in as a Scala sequence object rather than as an array.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to sort on repeated parameters, does it? You could just write them down in the correct order in the first place. I guess the OP just didn't understand the `Array` type.

Comment: @drexin - That's a good point! However, what if the parameters have dynamic values? E.g., `imperativeBubbleSort(a,b,c,d,e)`. I still agree that just passing in an array is probably a better solution—but I also wanted to illustrate how to use varargs. Hopefully he'll see how much more complex this is (requiring a ClassTag) and go with the array instead.